# Is it possible to set a query timeout for slick-hikaricp?

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, hikaricp

I have a play-scala application which uses slick-hikaricp. I know there is way to set connection timeout but I would like to set a query timeout. I have some slow queries and if they take more than 3 seconds I would like to stop them with timeout setting. I searched and bonecp provides a parameter named as 'queryExecuteTimeLimit' but I couldn't find a setting for hikaricp. Do you know how can I set a query timeout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using Slick's [`withStatementParameters`](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/14db18d7974ade35bf6d6dbc97bfe6e0490807c8/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/JdbcActionComponent.scala#L114) to [`setQueryTimeout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout-int-)? For example,

```
myTable.result.withStatementParameters(statementInit = _.setQueryTimeout(3))
```

This should throw `SQLTimeoutException` if query takes longer than 3 seconds.